# Is there a way to link a static site to Pyramid app without being part of Pyramid?

Tags: html, pyramid

Maybe this is a question for my web host but I thought I'd try here, too.

I have a static HTML "site" for my homepage, "www.mycompany.com"; it's just a collection of a landing page, and about page, etc.  I also have a Pyramid web application that is the "application" part of my site.

Due to some early decisions in develoment we didn't want the HTML site to be part of and served by Pyramid.  So on my web host I have a static HTML site "app", and a Pyramid "app". The HTML site is the root domain, and then the Pyramid app is set up to use a url prefix off of the root domain.  So what I end up with is:

```
www.mycompany.com - HTML site 
www.mycompany.com/app - Pyramid app
```

And then basically everything under the Pyramid app starts with "/app/".  It works, but it seems clumsy.  Is there a way to merge it all together somehow without having to have the actual HTML served from Pyramid?  What I'd like to be able to do is edit/update the HTML code without having to tie it to the Pyramid application where I'd need to restart the Pyramid process for changes to get picked up (unless that's not how it would work?).  I know I have a static path within Pyramid but that still gets processed by Pyramid (or nginix in this case?) to be served, right?

Ideally I've have www.mycompany.com and it's related static pages (mycompany.com, mycompany.com/about.html, etc.) and the Pyramid pages would be served off of that, too (mycompany.com/admin, mycompany.com/profile, etc.)  Is there a clean way to set this up?

Answer (score 0):

You can use nginx's `try_files` directive to attempt to return static files from some root, and if it fails then you can `proxy_pass` the request to Pyramid.